# Using the secret admin frontname in a new adminhtml router

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, security, routing

I have a module that uses an abnormal naming convention.  Instead of `NAMESPACE_MODULE` it uses `NAMESPACE_MODULE_SUBMODULE`:

```
$ find app/code/community -type f
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Bar/etc/config.xml
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Bar/Model/Observer.php
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Core/etc/config.xml
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Core/Model/Observer.php
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Foo/controllers/IndexController.php
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Foo/etc/config.xml
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Foo/Helper/Data.php
app/code/community/Acme/ModuleName/Foo/Model/Foo.php
```

This works fine for everything except controllers, since they don't use the autoloader.  Specifically this piece from core:

```
# File app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php

public function getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $realModule);
    $realModule = implode('_', array_splice($parts, 0, 2));
    $file = Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', $realModule);
    if (count($parts)) {
        $file .= DS . implode(DS, $parts);
    }
    $file .= DS.uc_words($controller, DS).'Controller.php';
    return $file;
}
```

Because `array_splice` is only taking `2` parts it ends up looking for my controllers in `Acme/ModuleName/controllers` instead of `Acme/ModuleName/Foo/controllers`.  To work around this I am using my own router with a modified `getControllerFileName()` that can correctly load the controller file.

This works great in the `frontend`, where there is no issue with accessing the `frontname` directly (`example.com/modulenamefoo`).

However, now I need to create an `adminhtml` controller/router.  I've set things up the same:

```
<adminhtml>
    <routers>
        <acme_modulename_admin>
            <use>acme_modulename_admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Acme_ModuleName_Core</module>
                <frontName>acme_modulename_admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </acme_modulename_admin>
    </routers>
</adminhtml>
```

And this too is working.  However, I've hardcoded the `frontname` which means anyone can access `example.com/acme_modulename_admin` and brute force my admin login.

Is it possible to use the same adminhtml `frontname` in a different router?

I've tried overriding `collectRoutes()` in my router so that it uses the configured secret admin frontname but it is not working.  Even throwing in a

```
$this->addModule(
    (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_ADMINHTML_ROUTER_FRONTNAME),
    array('Acme_ModuleName_Core'),
    'adminhtml'
);
```

doesn't work.

Even if I modify `app/etc/local.xml` and set the secret `frontname` for `admin/routers/acme_modulename_admin/args/frontName`, what's the magic that replaces `adminhtml` in things like the menu urls in `adminhtml.xml` or `$this->getUrl('adminhtml/foo/*')`?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you try in your <args></args> section to use <modules>
 <Acme_ModuleName_Core before="Mage_Adminhtml">Acme_ModuleName_Core_Adminhtml</Acme_ModuleName_Core>
</modules> ? Instead of what you have now?

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your config.xml to looks like below and remove the custom router you created.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    .........
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Acme_ModuleName_Core before="Mage_Adminhtml">Acme_ModuleName_Core_Adminhtml</Acme_ModuleName_Core>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    ........
<config>
```